# my php code to connect with database for android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

im trying to connect my android app with the data base im using for the website but somehow it doesnt want to  connect

this is my java code im using for the connect

### Android manifest i added

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses- 
  permission>
```

---

background.java

---

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import  android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class backgroundworker extends AsyncTask<String,Void, String> {
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
backgroundworker(Context ctx){
    context =ctx;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2//android/login.php";
    if (type.equals("login")){
        try {
            String Email = params[1];
            String Password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = 
   (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new 
     OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("Email","UTF- 
     8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Email,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("Password","UTF- 
     8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
      InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return null;
  }

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");

   }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();
  }

  @Override
   protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
     }
   }
```

---

login.java

---

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener 
{

Button liButton;
EditText liEmail, liPassword;
TextView liSignup;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    liEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.liEmail);
    liPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.liPassword);
    liButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.liButton);
    liSignup= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.liSignup);

    liButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    liSignup.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.liButton:
            String Email = liEmail.getText().toString();
            String Password = liPassword.getText().toString();
            String type = "login";
            BackgroundWorker backgroundworker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
            backgroundworker.execute(type, Email, Password);

            break;

        case R.id.liSignup:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, signup.class));
            break;
    }

}
}
```

---

this is my php code

---

```
 <?php

 $conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','signup');


 ?>
```

---

```
<?php

include('conn.php');

if(!session_id())

session_start();



   if (isset($_POST['Email'])
   and isset($_POST['Password'])
   and !empty($_POST['Email'])
   and !empty($_POST['Password'])){

     $Email = $_POST['Email'];
     $Password= $_POST['Password'];

     $getinfo = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email ='$Email' LIMIT 1";
     $res = mysqli_query($conn,$getinfo);
     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);


     if (mysqli_num_rows($res)>0) {

       $dbPassword = $row['Password'];
       $Password = PASSWORD_VERIFY($Password, $dbPassword);

       if ($Email == $row ['Email'] and $Password == $dbPassword) {

         $id = $row['id'];
         $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

         exit();

       } else{
         echo 'Wrong Email or Password.';
       }


     } else{
      echo 'Wrong Email or Password.';
     }

   }
   ?>
```

i believe my java code is right but im not sure what to do with my php if there is something wrong

Comment: this `and $Password == $dbPassword` is wrong. You already password_verified, the return is a boolan, so it should be `and $Password`. Better rename the return of `password_verify()` to smth like `$passwordVerified` to reduce confusion... And you don't need to re-check if `$Email == $row ['Email']`, because you queried for it already.

Comment: _sidenote_: you are open to sql-injection (because you use use-input directly in a query)! Use prepared statements!

Comment: also you should return something meaningful on success (maybe a json `{"success":true}` with an authtoken to re-connect?), and idealy change http status header on failure

Comment: ok im lost because im very new to this so i should remove ==$dbpassword and change $password in password_verify to $passwordVerified and remove ==$row['Email] ..and  i dont know what should i do exactly with the last comment as its my first android project

Comment: about the last comment: google "Sql injection" and read & use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line

```
if ($Email == $row ['Email'] and $Password == $dbPassword) {
```

is wrong/the problem. You already password_verified, which returns a boolan, so it should be.

```
if ($Email == $row ['Email'] and $Password) {
```

And you don't need to re-check if $Email == $row ['Email'], because you queried for it already.

So you can reduce your code to:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($res)>0) {
   $dbPassword = $row['Password'];

   if (PASSWORD_VERIFY($Password, $dbPassword)) {
     $id = $row['id'];
     $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
     exit();

   } else {
   //...
```

Comment: still it wont show echo which means its not connected

Comment: _"wont show echo"_ you don't show anything when the login is successful, you only show _"Wrong Email or Password."_ on failure.

Comment: it wont show echo for wrong email or password it just show only login status

Comment: it doesnt echo anything from php for the wrong password or email  it only shows login status from the android code

Comment: i know im might sound idiotic but its my first android project and the php code works fine for the html and it just so confusing

Comment: Where and how do you check what php is returning? This isn't shown in the android code (or I can't find it)

Comment: after a good sleep i found out that the problem in the android code thanks alot for the help and for the sql injection note